# Gradually scroll textbox when button it clicked

Tags: c#

I need to get a rich text box to scroll slowly when you press a button. I have only found codes that teleport you instantly to the end of a box but I need it to slowly scroll down at a readable pace.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.SelectionStart <= textBox2.TextLength) 
    {
        textBox2.SelectionStart += 30;
        textBox2.ScrollToCaret();
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

This code does scroll but it is to fast and I need to slow it down.

Comment: Take a look at [dot-net-transitions](https://github.com/UweKeim/dot-net-transitions) (assuming you are using WinForms).

Comment: im new to c# man I don't know how to use any of that

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion of  Uwe Keim here is the steps you have to do in order to use dot-net-transitions(assuming you are using WinForms).

In your Package Manager Console type:

Install-Package dot-net-transitions -Version 1.2.1

Then press enter.

This will install the NuGet Package so you can use the transitions library.

[image]

In your form I assume you have a text box and a button eg:

[image]

Right click the button on the form and select properties.

From properties click  the event button (it looks like a lighting bolt)

Then double click the Action Click.

[image]

This will create the click event for your button and will open the form code behind.

Then put this code in the button click event:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Transition t = new Transition(new TransitionType_EaseInEaseOut(2000));
        t.add(this.textBox1, "Top", 200);
        t.run();
    }
```

***Note***

You need to tell VS that you are using Transition therefor in your form you must declare the following

`using Transitions;`

I have called my textbox textBox1 you might need to change that reference to the name you have used for your text box.

This would be your form

```
using System;
using Transitions;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Transition t = new Transition(new TransitionType_EaseInEaseOut(2000));
            t.add(this.textBox1, "Top", 200);
            t.run();
        }
    }
}
```